# Core dump generates when Sytemd starts a c program that opens a link every few hours

Tags: c, linux, systemd

I am trying to write a program that opens up the google meet link for a particular class four minutes before it starts.

The program works perfectly fine when I run it directly from the command line, but when I launch it using a systemd service, it fails with a core-dump error.

here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple G Meet Autojoiner

Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/sgma

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here is the program it's trying to launch:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libnotify/notify.h>

typedef struct {
    int hour;
    int min;
    char *sub;
    char *link;
} Class;

const char FILE_NAME[] = "/schedule.txt";
const int NUM_CLASSES = 24;

void notify(char *class_name)
{
    notify_init ("Joining Class");
    NotifyNotification * Hello = notify_notification_new (class_name, "Starting in a few mins", "dialog-information");
    notify_notification_show (Hello, NULL);
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(Hello));
    notify_uninit();
}

void get_schedule(FILE *file, Class schedule[NUM_CLASSES], int current_day)
{
    char line[100];
    int hour;
    char dayfound = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        if ((line[0] == '[' && atoi(&line[1]) == current_day)) {
            dayfound = 1;
            continue;
        }

        /* Ignore the rest of the file */
        if (dayfound && line[0] == '\n') {
            dayfound = 0;
            break;
        }

        if (dayfound) {
            hour = atoi(strtok(line, ":"));
            schedule[hour - 9].hour = hour;
            schedule[hour - 9].min = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
            schedule[hour - 9].sub  = strdup(strtok(NULL, "\t")); /* We copy it first because strtok returns a pointer */
            schedule[hour - 9].link = strdup(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        }
    }
}

void join_meet(Class schedule[NUM_CLASSES], time_t now)
{
    struct tm *current_local;
    int cur_min;
    int cur_hour;
    int min_left;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLASSES; ++i) {

        now = time(NULL);
        current_local = localtime(&now);
        cur_min = current_local->tm_min;
        cur_hour = current_local->tm_hour;

        if (schedule[i].hour != -1) {
            if (cur_hour <= schedule[i].hour) {
                min_left = (schedule[i].hour - cur_hour) * 60 + schedule[i].min - cur_min - 4;
                if (min_left < 0) continue;
                sleep(min_left * 60);
                if (fork() == 0) {
                    notify(schedule[i].sub); 
                    execlp("xdg-open", "xdg-open", schedule[i].link, NULL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *local = localtime(&now);
    int current_day = local->tm_wday;

    char full_path[100];
    strcpy(full_path, getenv("XDG_DATA_HOME"));
    strncat(full_path, FILE_NAME, 100 - strlen(full_path) - 1);

    FILE *file = fopen(full_path, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror(full_path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Class schedule[NUM_CLASSES];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLASSES; ++i)
        schedule[i].hour = -1;

    get_schedule(file, schedule, current_day);

    fclose(file);

    join_meet(schedule, now);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strncat(getenv("XDG_DATA_HOME"), FILE_NAME, 30)` - you can't append to a string returned by `getenv`

Comment: It works when I run it from the commandline

Comment: It doesn't change this fact. Copy the output of `getenv` into adequately large buffer (for both `XDG_DATA_HOME` and `FILE_NAME`) and then concatenate with it

Comment: is this what's causing systemd to print a core dumped error?

Comment: It is one of possible reasons. Relevant standard citation: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.6p4 "*The getenv function returns a pointer to a string associated with the matched list member. The string pointed to shall not be modified by the program...*"

Comment: Plus: `getenv()` can return NULL, and you dont check for this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have changed the code like you had sugggested, but I am still getting the core dumped error.

Comment: Okay after trying out @wildplasser suggestion, I checked if I getenv returns null, after fixing that my program is exiting, which means getenv is returning null, how do I get getenv to return the path when running from systemd?